# Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms web driver firefox

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I got the following issue in production newly never seen this before. My selenium version 2.42.2 and in server we using firefox 31.0 to do automation test. I have googled and couldn't find relevant solution. I have attached the log here and need of possible cause of this exception.

```
Sat Dec 09 17:33:31 IST 2017: ******Scheduler Starting******
Sat Dec 09 17:33:31 IST 2017: *****Service Started.***
Sat Dec 09 17:34:02 IST 2017: ******Scheduler Started******
Sat Dec 09 18:01:38 IST 2017: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms
Build info: version: '2.42.2', revision: '6a6995d', time: '2014-06-03 17:42:03'
System info: host: 'SCRAP_SERVER', ip: '192.168.1.32', os.name: 'Windows Server 2008', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.0', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.internal.SocketLock.lock(SocketLock.java:98)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:84)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:95)
    at com.ppts.vgreports.executer.ScrapReportExecuter.execute(ScrapReportExecuter.java:134)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)

Sat Dec 09 19:06:09 IST 2017: 2017-12-09 Current day Started.
Sat Dec 09 19:07:24 IST 2017: 2017-12-09 Current day Completed.
Sat Dec 09 19:32:25 IST 2017: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(D:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7059; process output follows: 
1512828072222   addons.manager  DEBUG   Application has been upgraded
1512828072793   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm: ["XPIProvider"]
1512828072794   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/LightweightThemeManager.jsm: ["LightweightThemeManager"]
1512828072795   addons.xpi  DEBUG   startup
1512828073551   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
1512828073551   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
1512828073824   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: C:\Windows\TEMP\anonymous1082024976265747594webdriver-profile\extensions\webdriver-staging
1512828073835   addons.xpi  DEBUG   checkForChanges
1512828074598   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Directory state JSON differs: cache [] state [{"name":"winreg-app-global","addons":{"{20a82645-c095-46ed-80e3-08825760534b}":{"descriptor":"C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v3.5\\Windows Presentation Foundation\\DotNetAssistantExtension","mtime":1395978262666,"rdfTime":1213257870000}}},{"name":"app-global","addons":{"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"descriptor":"D:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","mtime":1500376842070,"rdfTime":1405567032000}}},{"name":"app-profile","addons":{"fxdriver@googlecode.com":{"descriptor":"C:\\Windows\\TEMP\\anonymous1082024976265747594webdriver-profile\\extensions\\fxdriver@googlecode.com","mtime":1512828029169,"rdfTime":1512828018138}}}]
1512828074602   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Opening XPI database C:\Windows\TEMP\anonymous1082024976265747594webdriver-profile\extensions.json
1512828074603   addons.xpi  DEBUG   New add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com installed in app-profile
*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
1512828076448   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon app-profile:fxdriver@googlecode.com visible
1512828076449   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1512828076449   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1512828076449   addons.xpi  DEBUG   New add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} installed in app-global
1512828076705   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon app-global:{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} visible
1512828076705   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1512828076705   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1512828076705   addons.xpi  DEBUG   New add-on {20a82645-c095-46ed-80e3-08825760534b} installed in winreg-app-global
1512828076919   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon winreg-app-global:{20a82645-c095-46ed-80e3-08825760534b} visible
1512828076919   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1512828076919   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1512828078117   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
1512828078117   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
1512828078117   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
1512828091438   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1512828091692   addons.manager  DEBUG   shutdown
1512828091692   addons.xpi  DEBUG   shutdown
1512828091692   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   shutdown
1512828091694   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1512828095189   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1512828095189   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 16
1512828095189   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Notifying XPI shutdown observers
1512828095191   addons.manager  DEBUG   Async provider shutdown done
1512828142706   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm: ["XPIProvider"]
1512828142707   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/LightweightThemeManager.jsm: ["LightweightThemeManager"]
1512828142708   addons.xpi  DEBUG   startup

Build info: version: '2.42.2', revision: '6a6995d', time: '2014-06-03 17:42:03'
System info: host: 'SCRAP_SERVER', ip: '192.168.1.32', os.name: 'Windows Server 2008', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.0', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:130)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:95)
    at com.ppts.vgreports.executer.ScrapReportExecuter.execute(ScrapReportExecuter.java:134)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7059 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
1512828072222   addons.manager  DEBUG   Application has been upgraded
1512828072793   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm: ["XPIProvider"]
1512828072794   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/LightweightThemeManager.jsm: ["LightweightThemeManager"]
1512828072795   addons.xpi  DEBUG   startup
1512828073551   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
1512828073551   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
1512828073824   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: C:\Windows\TEMP\anonymous1082024976265747594webdriver-profile\extensions\webdriver-staging
1512828073835   addons.xpi  DEBUG   checkForChanges
1512828074598   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Directory state JSON differs: cache [] state [{"name":"winreg-app-global","addons":{"{20a82645-c095-46ed-80e3-08825760534b}":{"descriptor":"C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v3.5\\Windows Presentation Foundation\\DotNetAssistantExtension","mtime":1395978262666,"rdfTime":1213257870000}}},{"name":"app-global","addons":{"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"descriptor":"D:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","mtime":1500376842070,"rdfTime":1405567032000}}},{"name":"app-profile","addons":{"fxdriver@googlecode.com":{"descriptor":"C:\\Windows\\TEMP\\anonymous1082024976265747594webdriver-profile\\extensions\\fxdriver@googlecode.com","mtime":1512828029169,"rdfTime":1512828018138}}}]
1512828074602   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Opening XPI database C:\Windows\TEMP\anonymous1082024976265747594webdriver-profile\extensions.json
1512828074603   addons.xpi  DEBUG   New add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com installed in app-profile
*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
1512828076448   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon app-profile:fxdriver@googlecode.com visible
1512828076449   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1512828076449   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1512828076449   addons.xpi  DEBUG   New add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} installed in app-global
1512828076705   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon app-global:{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} visible
1512828076705   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1512828076705   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1512828076705   addons.xpi  DEBUG   New add-on {20a82645-c095-46ed-80e3-08825760534b} installed in winreg-app-global
1512828076919   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon winreg-app-global:{20a82645-c095-46ed-80e3-08825760534b} visible
1512828076919   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1512828076919   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1512828078117   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
1512828078117   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
1512828078117   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
1512828091438   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1512828091692   addons.manager  DEBUG   shutdown
1512828091692   addons.xpi  DEBUG   shutdown
1512828091692   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   shutdown
1512828091694   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1512828095189   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1512828095189   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 16
1512828095189   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Notifying XPI shutdown observers
1512828095191   addons.manager  DEBUG   Async provider shutdown done
1512828142706   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm: ["XPIProvider"]
1512828142707   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/LightweightThemeManager.jsm: ["LightweightThemeManager"]
1512828142708   addons.xpi  DEBUG   startup

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
    ... 9 more
```

Am new to selenium and no idea why this issue is occurs. i have searched over and found most of the answers are "Browser may be upgraded or selenium and Firefox version may getting conflict". But i have ensured that selenium version and Firefox version. It is not upgraded. From year ago we are using Firefox version as 31.0 only. am stuck with this issue.

Comment: Check your FF version as it might have been upgraded automatically. If that's the case, uninstall it and download the version you need manually and reinstall it. Make sure that you configure FF not to perform automatic updates

Comment: i have checked the version. Version is same and it's not upgraded. Is there any other possible cases @EugeneS

Comment: I see some messages about addons that you have in your FF. Do you need them for automated tests? If not, try removing them from FF

Comment: Error says it all `WebDriverException: Unable to bind to locking port 7054`. Clean your Project from the IDE and retest.